# error in production when using redis for cache and session

Tags: redis

I've added this to the array that is returned in `config/app.php`:

```
'components' => [
        'redis' => [
            'class' => yii\redis\Connection::class,
            'hostname' => App::env('REDIS_HOST'),
            'port' => APP::env('REDIS_PORT'),
            'password' => ''
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => yii\redis\Cache::class,
            'defaultDuration' => 86400,
            'keyPrefix' => App::env('APP_ID') ?: 'CraftCMS',
        ],

        'session' => function() {
            // Get the default component config
            $config = App::sessionConfig();

            // Override the class to use Redis' session class
            $config['class'] = yii\redis\Session::class;

            // Instantiate and return it
            return Craft::createObject($config);
        },
        
    ]
```

This all works find when my environment is in `dev` and `devMode` is on.

When I switch to production, I get an internal server error. I don't know what the issue is because it doesn't give me the full logs.

Answer (score 1):

Luckily, someone else had this problem: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/7617#issuecomment-786715807

The issue was because of leaving the password blank. devMode did not care, but production did. Had to remove the password entirely